Changes on top level of nextjs app only effect the index page
I have a next.js app using Bulma, and a ServiceProvider.
I import bulma and this provider at the top level of the application. This would be in my layout.js file, however the changes there don't persist.
When you go to a subpage, bulma's css stops working and the code errors saying my useSession isn't properly wrapped in the provider.
This is my layout.js:
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "bulma/css/bulma.min.css";
import Provider from "@/components/Provider";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "BD-Util",
  description: "",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Provider>
          {children}
        </Provider>
      </body>
    </html >
  );
}

This is my page.js:
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <section className="hero is-fullheight">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="hero-body is-flex-direction-column is-justify-content-center">
          <h1 className="title">BD-Util</h1>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

I'll include a screenshot of my apps structure as well.
App Folder Structure

Looking at the screenshot of your app's structure, it doesn't seem to be set up correctly. Currently, you created the page files under pages folder instead of app folder. Also, you will have to rename your page index.jsx files to page.jsx.

For example, to create your index page for the / route, add the
page.jsx file inside the app directory.
Then, to create further pages, create a new folder under the app
directory and add the page.jsx file inside it. For example, to
create a page for the /dashboard route, create a new folder called
dashboard, and add the page.jsx file inside it.

Look at the screenshots below.
Your current folder set up:

Correct set up:

Check the Next.js official documentation for further details.
